# Diophantine equations and recurrence sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, diophantine-equations

I was working on the diophantine equation $7x^2+y^2=2^n$ for each natural $n\geq 3$. I proved by induction that $(x_n,y_n)$ is an integer solution for  $n\geq 3,$ where $x_3=y_3=1$ and
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+y_n}{2} $$
$$y_{n+1}=\frac{7x_n-y_n}{2} $$
So I obtained a family of infinite solutions for each $n$ given by a system of recurrence sequences.

**I wonder if there is a general theory about this, which relate diophantine equations with recurrence sequences**.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not exactly a theory, but a [good starting point](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Diophantine-Equations-Problem-Based-Approach/dp/0817645489).

Comment: Also, download [this pdf](http://docplayer.net/29920320-Diophantine-equations-florian-luca.html) with the very 1st occasion!

Comment: I already had the book, but thanks for your comment and also for the PDF document. It will help for sure.

Answer (score 3):

In the ring $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-7}]$ the algebraic integers are of the form $\frac a2+\frac b2\sqrt{-7}$ where $a,b$ are integers of the same parity (both odd or both even.)

It’s a bit long to describe in an answer, but your $(x_n,y_n)$ can be seen as $$\frac{x_n}2+\frac{y_n}2\sqrt{-7}=\left(\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{-7}\right)^{n-2}$$

More generally, if:

$$\frac x2+\frac y2\sqrt{-7}=\left(\frac a2+\frac b2\sqrt{-7}\right)^k$$ then
$\frac{x^2+7y^2}4=\left(\frac{a^2+7b^2}4\right)^k.$

So you can solve $x^2+7y^2=11^k$ using $a=4,b=2.$

This kind of argument works for any $\sqrt{D},$ where $D$ is square-free. If $D\equiv 1\pmod 4$ you have to use the half-integers, like for $-7,$ but for other $D$ you only are allowed to take $a+b\sqrt D$ where $a,b$ are integers.

Study [Quadratic Fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_field?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: I've probably mentioned, I bought Lehman and can recommend it for students https://bookstore.ams.org/dol-52/  Clever, I think, to carry binary quadratic forms and field  ideals all through the book

Comment: Wow thanks Thomas. Your answer was of help. +1